# Regular Expression to find all except digits and decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

the regular express `/\D/g` identifies all non numeric characters and the following code will replace the letter 'q' and decimal '.' in `str` and result in `10025`

```
  var str = "10q0.25"; 
  var result = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

How can the regex be changed so as to allow the decimal point also and resulting in  `100.25` ?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is almost correct, but it will remove all non-numeric characters. My regex consists of a group or characters, which should remain in string, `[ ]` is a group of characters to match, `[^ ]` means group of characters not to match (inverted match), so `[^0-9.]` means that you want to replace every character except `0` through `9` and `.` (`0-9`) with an empty string `''`

```js
var str = "10q0.25"; 
var result = str.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

console.log(result)
```